# Change actionListener (actionPerformed) on second click

Tags: java, actionlistener, actionevent

The functionality of this small program is:
Click on a button, click on the red border button and change the action(change color of the buttons - from the red border button to the blue border button)...but even JOptionPane is ok, as long as I manage to change the action.

Please find reviewed code for the Panel Class:....which it is still not working.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Panel 
{

    private JButton[][] bu1 = new JButton[10][10];
    public Panel(JFrame frame)
    {   
        super();

        JPanel pCenter = new JPanel();
        JPanel pTop = new JPanel();

        frame.add(pCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(pTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel Grid10x10 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,10));

        pCenter.add(Grid10x10);

        for(int c = 0; c< 10; c++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r< 10; r++)
            {
                bu1[c][r] = new JButton("X");
                Grid10x10.add(bu1[c][r]);

                final int i = c;
                final int j = r;

                ActionListener[] listeners = bu1[i][j].getActionListeners();
                for (ActionListener l : listeners) 
                {
                bu1[i][j].removeActionListener(l);
                }

                bu1[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        int f = (3-1);

                        Object redButton = new Object();
                        if(e.getSource() == redButton)
                        {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"row ");
                        }

                        bu1[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));

                        if ((j+f)<=9)
                        {
                            bu1[i][j+f].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
                            redButton = bu1[i][j+f];

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"move your 1st click more to the center");
            }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm stacked!! I am relatively new to java and I have been days searching the web to solve my problem without success, its now time to ask for your help.

I cannot...(actually do not know) how to change the actionlistener (actionPerformed) after the second click in an array of JButtons. Please find the code below so that you can guide me.

On the 1st click on the grid, the border of the button clicked will change to 'blue' and another button will change its boarder to 'red'. I need to change action when the 'red' bordered button is clicked, lets say change color of the buttons from the 'red' to the 'blue' buttons.

Your help is much appreciated!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class ChangeGrid
{

    private JButton[][] bu1 = new JButton[10][10];
    public ChangeGrid(JFrame frame)
    {
        super();

        JPanel pCenter = new JPanel();
        JPanel pTop = new JPanel();

        frame.add(pCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(pTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel Grid10x10 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,10));

        pCenter.add(Grid10x10);

        for(int c = 0; c< 10; c++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r< 10; r++)
            {
                bu1[c][r] = new JButton("X");
                Grid10x10.add(bu1[c][r]);

                final int i = c;
                final int j = r;

                bu1[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        int f = (3-1);

                        bu1[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));

                        if ((j+f)<=9)
                        {
                            bu1[i][j+f].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"move your 1st click more to the center");
            }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class GUIFrame extends JFrame
{
    public GUIFrame()
    {
        super("Grid 10 x 10");

        this.setSize(1350, 700);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(GUIFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
        {

            JFrame frame = new GUIFrame();
            ChangeGrid pC = new ChangeGrid(frame);
            frame.pack();
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is exactly needed? I don't understand your words.

Comment: Assign actions to buttons and each will perform its own work.  What seems to be a problem?

Comment: run program, click on a button, click on the red border button and change the action(change color of the buttons - from the red border button to the blue border button)...but even JOptionPane is ok, as long as I manage to change the action.

Comment: Theoretically, you *could* just call `bu1[i][j].removeActionListener(this);` in the `actionPerformed` method, and then add a new one by calling `bu1[i][j].addActionListener`. But this is horrible design. Maybe you should represent the *state* of the buttons somewhere (maybe in an array like `Color borderColors[][]`) and then modify this state accordingly, but this is just a guess based on the (vague) description until now...

Comment: @PM77-1..can you guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly clear on your end goal, but to change the action listener you first need to remove the current listener and add a new one.

```
ActionListener[] listeners = bu1[i][j].getActionListeners();
for (ActionListener l : listeners) {
    bu1[i][j].removeActionListener(l);
}
bu1[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
...
});
```

It might be better however if you keep a reference to the button which was turned red into a separate variable. And instead of changing action listener just check if the current button is the one which is currently red

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    ...
    if(e.getSource() == redButton){
        //do something with red button
    }
    if ((j+f)<=9)
    {
        bu1[i][j+f].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2));
        redButton = bu1[i][j+f];
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but did not work. The only difference was that I had to declare the 'redButton' as Object. Please find reviewed code for the Panel Class:

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use MouseListener, MouseListener have getClickCount() , you can use

```
if(e.getClickCount()==1)
{

}


if(e.getClickCount()==2)
{


}
```

Comment: I was suggested not to use MouseListner on JButtons...still thanks for comment!

Answer (score 0):

another solution is using propertyChangeListener

make your own property ,example code

```
button.addPropertyChangeListener("grid",new PropertyChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
              System.out.println(evt.getNewValue());
          }
      });
```